# how to add click event to multiple items with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery code that gets json data and list them in a ul list. I want to populate this Items on click.

`$('#places)` is a **ul list**.

```
$.each(data, function (id, item) {                  
   $('#places').append('<a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-lat=' + item.lat + ' data-lng=' + item.lng + '>' + item.name + '</a>');      
});
```

Ul list items are links that included latitude and longitute values. I want to add click event to that links. Which I click link zoom to that location. How can add event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `on()` to handle the dynamically generated link,

```
$('#places').on('click','a.list-group-item',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   //code here
});
```

You can use `e.preventDefault();` for preventing browser default action.

Comment: you forgot something for it to work. (edit: yep thats it)

Comment: this returns "e" as x.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: function, timeStamp: 1391427979506, jQuery110103376125982031226: true…} But I want use my Item object

Answer (score 0):

You can apply jquery click event on class "list-group-item"

```
$( ".list-group-item" ).click(function() {
var id = $(this).attr('id');//clicked <li> id
    var lat = $(this).attr('data-lat');//clicked <li> data-lat
    var lng = $(this).attr('data-lng');//clicked <li> data-lng
    //code for zooming 
});
```